How to optimize PySpark code to calculate Jaccard Similarity for a huge dataset
I have a huge PySpark dataframe that contains 250 million rows, with columns ItemA and ItemB. I'm trying to calculate the Jaccard Similarity M_ij that can run efficiently and takes a short amount of time to complete. My code is as follows.
# Group by ItemA and collect all ItemB values as a set
item_sets = df.groupby('ItemA').agg(collect_set('ItemB').alias('ItemB_set'))

# Repartition the dataframe to ensure even distribution of data
item_sets = item_sets.repartition(100)

# Cross join the sets with each other (thus, creating all pairs of ItemA)
cross_item_sets = item_sets.alias('i').crossJoin(item_sets.alias('j'))

# Calculate the intersection and union for each pair
def jaccard_similarity(row):
    set_i = set(row['i']['ItemB_set'])
    set_j = set(row['j']['ItemB_set'])

    intersection_size = len(set_i.intersection(set_j))
    union_size = len(set_i.union(set_j))

    return Row(ItemA_i=row['i']['ItemA'], ItemA_j=row['j']['ItemA'], M_ij=intersection_size / union_size if union_size > 0 else 0)

# Apply the function
similarity_rdd = cross_item_sets.rdd.map(jaccard_similarity).repartition(200)

# Specify the schema for the dataframe
schema = StructType([
    StructField("ItemA", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ItemB", StringType(), True),
    StructField("jaccard_sim", FloatType(), True)
])

# Convert the RDD back to Dataframe
similarity_df = spark.createDataFrame(similarity_rdd, schema)

# Show results
similarity_df.show(10, truncate=False)

When I looked at the Spark Web UI after leaving the code to run for 2 hours, I see
Stages: Succeeded/Total --> 0/4
Tasks (for all stages): Succeeded/Total --> 0/10155 (14 running)

I believe the above is at the similarity_df.show() part.
I can't increase the amount of Spark cluster resources given to me.
How can I get the code to run?

Maybe another approach is helpful?

Are you trying to create all pair (with crossJoin) of 250_000_000 rows resulting in 250_000_000 * 250_000_000 = 62_500_000_000_000_000 items to compute while calling an expensive Python function for each pair? If so, there is no chance for this algorithm to be fast. You need to use another algorithm/approach. Indeed, with 20 ns per call (very small for a Python function) and 1000 cores, this will at least takes 2 week of computation. In general, you cannot use O(n**2) algorithms (or more expensive ones) for huge datasets : this is not reasonable.
